# SQL find two consecutive days in a reservation system

Tags: mysql, sql

Extending on this question:
[hotel reservation system SQL query: identify when one specific room is available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5606824/hotel-reservation-system-sql-query-identify-when-one-specific-room-is-available)

Using the schema listed in the question above, how can I have a query that says "Find me a room for 2 consecutive days thats available in this week?"

Comment: Too much work reading that other stuff. Don't be lazy and post the query that you are having troubles with and the table schema nicely formatted on this question.

Comment: Show us the query you have so far...

Comment: So what is your parameter?  The date of the Sunday that begins the week?  The week number for the year?  Elaborate, pls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just join to the availability table twice

```
SELECT rooms.* FROM rooms, availability as a1, availability as a2
WHERE rooms.id = 123
AND a1.room_id = rooms.id
AND a2.room_id=  rooms.id
AND a1.date_occupied + 1 = a2.date_occupied
```

or, if we're not into writing SQL like its 1985:

```
SELECT rooms.* FROM rooms
JOIN availability a1 on a1.room_id = rooms.id
Join availability a2 on a2.room_id = rooms.id AND a1.date_occupied + 1 = a2.date_occupied
WHERE rooms.id = 123
```